# Correctly wrap a TikZ figure into/next to a list (itemize)

Tags: tikz-pgf, lists, environments, itemize

I'm trying to find a way to correctly put a `TikZ` figure at the left of a list, in such a way that the lines of the list below the figure will fit the entire paper width.

[image]

I was able to do this, but the lines below the figure don't fit the entire paper width.

[image]

I also tried `\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{2cm}` in order to have only the first 4 lines shorter, but the command messed all up.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   showframe, % mostra l'area di lavoro
   a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3cm,% per regolare i bordi a piacimento
   heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % per poter usare le lettere calligrafiche (comprende amsmath)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm} % per poter usare la fn indicatrice
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cancel} % per barrare una formula
\usepackage{pgfplots} % per costruire grafici e figure (comprende tikz che a sua volta comprende graphicx)
\usepackage{wrapfig} % per scrivere di fianco alle immagini
\usepackage{yhmath} % per l'arco sopra il testo
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % insieme reali
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{EQUAZIONI TRIGONOMETRICHE ELEMENTARI}
\end{center}
\underline{1\degree\  CASO} \  $\boxed{\sin x=c},\,c\in\R$\  (è sottointeso che $k\in\Z$)\\~\\
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.7\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item $c<-1\  \vee\  c>1:$ impossibile
\item $c=1: x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$
\item $c=0: x=0+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=\pi+2\pi k\  (\Leftrightarrow x=k\pi)$
\item $c=-1: x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k$
\item $0<c<1:$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sopra} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $c$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
$$x=\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k$$
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin c$ (funzione che restituisce l'angolo associato al valore del seno che ha come argomento)
\end{itemize}
\item $-1<c<0$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sotto} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $\abs{c}$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
\begin{align*} x&=(\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(2\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [0,2\pi] \\
x&=-\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(-\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [-\pi,\pi] \end{align*}
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin \abs{c}$
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[h]{0.2\linewidth}
\centering\vspace{-12cm}
%\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{2cm} % i tried this to wrap in the first 4 lines
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node [above] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.2) node [right] {$y$};
\draw (1,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.25,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=0.25cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (-0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.4,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=135,radius=0.4cm];
\draw (-1,0.71) -- (1,0.71) node [right] {$y=c$};
\draw (0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\draw (-0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{wrapfigure}
\end{minipage}


\newpage
\underline{1\degree\  CASO} \  $\boxed{\sin x=c},\,c\in\R$\  (è sottointeso che $k\in\Z$)
\begin{itemize}
\item $c<-1\  \vee\  c>1:$ impossibile
\item $c=1: x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$
\item $c=0: x=0+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=\pi+2\pi k\  (\Leftrightarrow x=k\pi)$
\item $c=-1: x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k$
\item $0<c<1:$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sopra} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $c$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
$$x=\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k$$
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin c$ (funzione che restituisce l'angolo associato al valore del seno che ha come argomento)
\end{itemize}
\item $-1<c<0$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sotto} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $\abs{c}$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
\begin{align*} x&=(\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(2\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [0,2\pi] \\
x&=-\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(-\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [-\pi,\pi] \end{align*}
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin \abs{c}$
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatic solutions are difficult. But if you know that the place is free you can easily put a picture there:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   showframe, % mostra l'area di lavoro
   a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3cm,% per regolare i bordi a piacimento
   heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % per poter usare le lettere calligrafiche (comprende amsmath)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm} % per poter usare la fn indicatrice
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cancel} % per barrare una formula
\usepackage{pgfplots} % per costruire grafici e figure (comprende tikz che a sua volta comprende graphicx)
\usepackage{wrapfig} % per scrivere di fianco alle immagini
\usepackage{yhmath} % per l'arco sopra il testo
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % insieme reali
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{EQUAZIONI TRIGONOMETRICHE ELEMENTARI}
\end{center}
\underline{1\degree\  CASO} \  $\boxed{\sin x=c},\,c\in\R$\  (è sottointeso che $k\in\Z$)
\begin{itemize}
\item $c<-1\  \vee\  c>1:$ impossibile
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\path[use as bounding box] (-1.2,1.3)--(2.3,1.3); %set the height and depth to zero
\draw [->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node [above] {$x$};
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.2) node [right] {$y$};
\draw (1,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.25,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=0.25cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (-0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.4,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=135,radius=0.4cm];
\draw (-1,0.71) -- (1,0.71) node [right] {$y=c$};
\draw (0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\draw (-0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\item $c=1: x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$
\item $c=0: x=0+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=\pi+2\pi k\  (\Leftrightarrow x=k\pi)$
\item $c=-1: x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k$
\item $0<c<1:$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sopra} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $c$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
$$x=\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k$$
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin c$ (funzione che restituisce l'angolo associato al valore del seno che ha come argomento)
\end{itemize}
\item $-1<c<0$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sotto} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $\abs{c}$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
\begin{align*} x&=(\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(2\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [0,2\pi] \\
x&=-\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(-\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [-\pi,\pi] \end{align*}
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin \abs{c}$
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Can you explain what is the purpose of the command `\path[use as bounding box] (-1.2,1.3)--(2.3,1.3)` ? I see that if I change the values of the second point a bit, I can move the figure left, right, up e down, that is good

Comment: The main point is to avoid that the picture has to much height and moves the items apart (comment the line to see what happens). That you can move it by changing the values is a useful side effect.

Answer (score 3):

I rearranged the `itemize` and `minipage` environments. Also set `\parindent=0pt` to prevent new paragraph to start with indentation, and included `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` (which is required when `pfgplots` is used)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   showframe, % mostra l'area di lavoro
   a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3cm,% per regolare i bordi a piacimento
   heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{mathtools} % per poter usare le lettere calligrafiche (comprende amsmath)
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm} % per poter usare la fn indicatrice
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{cancel} % per barrare una formula
\usepackage{pgfplots} % per costruire grafici e figure (comprende tikz che a sua volta comprende graphicx)
\usepackage{wrapfig} % per scrivere di fianco alle immagini
\usepackage{yhmath} % per l'arco sopra il testo
\usepackage{gensymb} % \degree

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} <-- Added
\parindent=0pt            <-- Added

\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}} % insieme reali
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\textbf{EQUAZIONI TRIGONOMETRICHE ELEMENTARI}
\end{center}

\underline{1\degree\  CASO} \  $\boxed{\sin x=c},\,c\in\R$\  (è sottointeso che $k\in\Z$)\\~\\

\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item $c<-1\  \vee\  c>1:$ impossibile
\item $c=1: x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$
\item $c=0: x=0+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=\pi+2\pi k\  (\Leftrightarrow x=k\pi)$
\item $c=-1: x=\frac{3}{2}\pi+2\pi k$
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
\centering
%\begin{wrapfigure}[4]{r}{2cm} % i tried this to wrap in the first 4 lines
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw [->] (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0) node [above] {$x$};    
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1.2) node [right] {$y$};
\draw (1,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=180,radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.25,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=45,radius=0.25cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (-0.9,0.9);
\draw [->] (0.4,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=135,radius=0.4cm];
\draw (-1,0.71) -- (1,0.71) node [right] {$y=c$};
\draw (0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\draw (-0.71,0.71) node [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{wrapfigure}
\end{minipage}

\begin{itemize}
\item $0<c<1:$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sopra} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $c$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
$$x=\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k$$
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin c$ (funzione che restituisce l'angolo associato al valore del seno che ha come argomento)
\end{itemize}
\item $-1<c<0$ la retta $y=c$ incontra la circonferenza in 2 punti distinti situati \textit{sotto} l'asse $x$, unendoli con l'origine otteniamo 2 angoli
\begin{itemize}
\item se $\abs{c}$ è un valore associato ad un angolo fondamentale $\alpha$ si ha
\begin{align*} x&=(\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(2\pi-\alpha)+2\pi k\quad     [0,2\pi] \\
x&=-\alpha+2\pi k\  \vee\  x=(-\pi+\alpha)+2\pi k\quad [-\pi,\pi]     \end{align*}
\item altrimenti al posto di $\alpha$ si mette $\arcsin \abs{c}$
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I think the other one is a bit better because is more simple and give the possibility to adjust the position of the figure up/down and left/right.

Comment: You are welcome. And sure it does. Do not worry, I am glad my answer helped you somehow.